# Entity Framework History of a Field

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-core-2.1

Is there any way, using EF Core (Code First), to get all entries where a column was something but the value is different now?

For example

```
Tab1 {
Id,
C1
}

Tab2 {
Id,
Tab1 tab1Entry,
C2,
.
.
}
```

I need to find a way to get the data from TAB 2, where tab1Entry.Id was or is something

Is there any way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand the question but if you are talking about being able to query previous updates then you would have to have a history of the updates, like an audit table or something.

Comment: this is what i need. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a feature called temporal tables in SQL Server and SQL Azure, which can create and maintain the history tables for you:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-2017

And you can use it with EF Core, but to achieve this you will need to use some raw SQL, probably this will change in the future, you can read more about this here:
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/4693
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt795184.aspx